# Java - print list in 2 or 3 columns

Tags: java, file, exception, io, printwriter

My program is running. but, I wonder, If the result can be printed in 2 or 3 columns because the list of names is long (69 names). I tried to use f.format before for loop and string.format into println but it is not working.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CommonBabyNames
{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       String filename;
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         
       ArrayList<String> boys = new ArrayList<String>();
       ArrayList<String> girls = new ArrayList<String>();
       ArrayList<String> common = new ArrayList<String>();

       System.out.print("Enter a filename for baby name ranking: ");
       filename = in.nextLine();
      
       loadFile(filename, boys, girls);
       findCommonNames(boys, girls, common);
       printCommonNames(common);
   }
  
   private static void loadFile(String filename, ArrayList<String> boys, ArrayList<String> girls)
   {
       try {
           Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(filename));
           while(inFile.hasNext()) {
               String line = inFile.nextLine();
               String[] values = line.split("\\s+");
               boys.add(values[1]);
               girls.add(values[3]);
           }
           inFile.close();
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           System.exit(1);
       }
      
   }
  
   private static void findCommonNames(ArrayList<String> boys, ArrayList<String> girls, ArrayList<String> common)
   {
       for(String b: boys){
           if(girls.contains(b))
               common.add(b);
       }
   }
  
   private static void printCommonNames( ArrayList<String> common)
   {
       System.out.println(common.size() + " names are used for both genders\n\n They are");
       for(String s:common)
           System.out.print(" " + s);
          
       System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Output:
Enter a file name for baby name ranking: babynamesranking2001.txt

69 names are used for both genders:

There are
Tyler
Ryan
Christian
Logan
Cameron
Hunter
Gabriel
Jordan
Angel
Alex
Devin
Dakota
Carson
Riley
Jaden
Hayden
Parker
Jayden
Alexis
Devon
Taylor
Peyton
Micah
Chandler
Ashton
Drew
Casey
Skyler
Avery
Jaime
Payton
Bailey
Quinn
Morgan
Skylar
Justice
Reese
Jessie
Kendall
Harley
Jaiden
Jaylin
Jamie
Addison
Ariel
Sage
Dominique
Devyn
Sidney
Amari
Armani
Baby
Reagan
Guadalupe
Shannon
Reilly
Shea
Kennedy
London
Jadyn
Raven
Courtney
Kelly
Kasey
Mackenzie
Jordyn
Aubrey
Jade
Rylee

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 19 seconds)

Comment: Just a simple approach, why not set a counter and print a new line after every third name maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private static void printCommonNames(Collection<String> commons, int width, int columnCount) {
    int column = 0;
    String format = "%" + width + "s";
    for (String name : commons) {
        System.out.printf(format, name);
        column = ++column % columnCount;
        if (column == 0) System.out.println();
    }
}
```

For test use

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] commons = {"qwe", "dsfsdhfjkrfnb", "werswdf", "dfsqqa", "asfdeqwds",
            "sasdfdqa", "dfdsasadf", "asdfdsa", "adf", "afdsasdf"};
    printCommonNames(Arrays.asList(commons), 16, 3);
}
```

Comment: Vitalii, testing as a new program works like I want it, but wen I add them to my program it is not working.                                                                                                        
private static void printCommonNames(Collection<String> commons, int width, int columnCount) {
       System.out.println(common.size() + " names are used for both genders\n\n They are");
       for(String s:common){
        System.out.printf(format, s);
        column = ++column % columnCount;
        if (column == 0) System.out.println();

Comment: You should replace your method by new impl and change method call line to `printCommonNames(common, 16, 3)`